# Update JFrame whenever MySQL table is updated

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jframe

I am creating a Form for restaurant management which has a `JTable` showing order details. The form is connected to mysql database 'Restaurant' in which 'orders' table is present.

Now when new data is added to table 'Orders' in 'Restaurant' database I want the form to update automatically.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does your programm add data on the DB or just want to update if the provider changes something and you are just consuming a API?

Comment: there are multiple JFrames, one of them is for customer inteface through which customer adds order into DB,now I want the frame at managers end to update whenever a customer adds something into orders table through his JFrame.

Comment: I would try the a timer schedduled update on customer frame or create a base which can consume and fire events if something chages.

Comment: thanx for the Idea.....i will try to implement...

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is to create a `java.util.Timer` or `javax.swing.Timer` and assign an `ActionEvent` to it to check for changes in set intervals.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions is using Listener Pattern.
When customer changes something in database, CustomerJFrame can notify it's listeners, that data has changed. OrdersJFrame can listen to CustomerJFrame and fetch needed data from db on notify